# If $f$ and $g$ are continuous, then max(f, g) is continuous and differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

If $f$ and $g$ are continuous on $[a, b]$ and differentiable on $(a, b)$, then $\max(f, g)$ is continuous on $[a, b]$ and differentiable on $(a, b)$.

I'm asked to either prove or disprove this statement.  So far I'm thinking that it's true because if a function is continuous and differentiable on an interval, it takes on it's max/min over the interval, but I don't know if this is correct, and if it is, I don't know how to prove it.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $f(x)=x$, $g(x)=-x$, $[a,b]=[-1,1]$

Comment: The part of the question after "So far I'm thinking" looks to me like an attempt at "proof by pun". You're talking there about the max of a function $f$ on an interval, the value $f(c)$ that is $\geq$ all the other values $f(z)$ for the same $f$ and other $z$'s.  The problem, on the other hand, concerns the max (or min) of two functions $f$ and $g$ which is a function whose value at any $x$ is the larger of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, with no reference to any other $z$'s. Although "max" occurs in both, it's applied in entirely different ways.

Comment: @1234: please don't make so many trivial edits so quickly!

Answer (score 5):

**Idea**

Consider $\lvert x \rvert = \max\{x, -x\}$.

Comment: So then I let f(x) = x and g(x) = -x.  Then let |x| = max{x,-x} which is a contradiction because |x| is not differentiable on the interval with f and g?

Answer (score 1):

Can use the fact that max (f,g) = {f + g + |f-g|}/2

Comment: Could you add more detail into how you'd use that fact? (I think there's a valid answer here, and some insight in that this fails because $|f-g|$ might not be differentiable, but this needs to be fleshed out further to be useful)

Comment: @Meelo Yeah I overlook that part. it is true that |f-g| might not be differentiable. Does that mean we need to assume f>0 and g>0 here?

Comment: @user Well, it means that we'd need that $f-g$ never changes signs - which would imply that $\max(f,g)$ equals $f$ or $g$. We could weaken that to requiring that if $f-g$ changes sign around a point, then at that point $f'-g'=0$. (In general, per mixedmath's answer, the statement is false)